# Transferir um pdf de uma aplicação WEB para uma aplicação desktop, em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicação-desktop, requisição

Tenho que fazer um trabalho para a faculdade utilizando C#, com o Visual Studio, onde um usuário acessa uma aplicação web, faz o upload de um arquivo, e envia para uma maquina desktop remota e salva em uma pasta específica.

Irei usar ASP.NET MVC na criação da aplicação WEB. Minha dúvida é, como posso fazer, que esse arquivo seja enviado para um computador remoto, selecionado pelo usuário, e seja salvo em uma pasta?

Pensei em usar uma aplicação desktop na maquina remota, que receberia essa requisição e salvaria o arquivo na pasta, qual o melhor tipo de projeto desktop eu devo desenvolver, para esse caso em específico?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você já parou pra pensar em como vai fazer pra sua aplicação web "enviar" algo pra uma aplicação desktop?

Comment: Eu pensei em usar Sockets ou FTP, mas o GOKU SSJGod deu a idéia de a aplicação desktop fazer o download direto de um pasta do servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta é muito ampla........

Você pode criar sua aplicação web para fazer o upload dos arquivos para um servidor web.

Já a segunda parte o mais indicado seria [windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx), que executaria em segundo plano assim como você especificou, bastaria ele ter acesso a pasta no servidor web e fazer o download dos arquivos para sua pasta especificar.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881392/how-to-copy-file-from-folder-to-another-folder-with-windows-service-c-sharp) tem um bom exemplo dese tipo de aplicação.

Comment: Interessante. Não pensei nessa situação, de a aplicação desktop acessar uma pasta no servidor.